# Parsing text File and extracting information in perl

Tags: perl, parsing, text

I have a code with multiple functions

```
void fun_one()

{

tempa=10;

tempb=10;

}

void fun_two()

{

tempc=12;

tempd=13;

}
```

I want perl code that extracts function name if i input variable name;

say I search for "tempa", it should extract "fun_one" into a variable;

say I search for "tempd", it should extract "fun_two" into a variable;

I have extracted line number

```
open my $code, '<', 'code.txt'  ;

my $keyword = "tempa";

my $regex = qr|\b($keyword)\b|;


while ($code>)

{

    while (/$regex/g)

    {

        print "$.\n";

    }

}
```

Output:3
I need some logic to extract fuction name.

thanks in advance

Comment: open my $code, '<', 'search.txt' ; 
my $keyword = "tempa";
 my $regex = qr|\b($keyword)\b|; 
while (<$code>) {
 while (/$regex/g) { 
print "$.\n";
 } }

Comment: please add th ro your question using edit function.

Answer (score 0):

You might need a parser instead of just regexes.

But...

```
sub find_function_using_variable {
  my $variable = shift;
  my $last_func="";
  while (<>) {
    $last_func = $1 if m/void (\w+)\(\)/;
    print $last_func."\n" if m/\Q$variable\E/;
  }
}
```